# How to create a JAXB Marshaller that takes a Generic object

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Essentially what I'm trying to do is create a marshaller that can take any class object I give it for example a car object or a person object and it must return a XML string.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
 public <T> String CreateXML(T objToSerialize)
    {
        String xml = "";
        try 
        {           

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(objToSerialize.getClass());
        Marshaller marshaler = context.createMarshaller(); 
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        marshaler.marshal(objToSerialize.getClass(),writer);
        xml = writer.toString();
            System.out.println(xml);
            return xml;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return xml;
    }
```

It gives me the following error:

> WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code, you marshal the class of the objectToSerialize
and not the object itself.
You can either change this line

```
 marshaler.marshal(objToSerialize.getClass(),writer);
 //to
 marshaler.marshal(objToSerialize,writer);
```

or try this code instead:

```
public static <T> String marshall(T data) {
    try {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(data.getClass());
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        StringWriter stringWriter=new StringWriter();
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT,true);
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(data, stringWriter);
        return stringWriter.toString();
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a generic conversion try this:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
JAXBContext.newInstance(((JAXBElement) argument).getDeclaredType()).createMarshaller().marshal(argument, sw);
sb.append(sw.toString());
```